# CSS display Angular expansion panel element in one line

Tags: html, css, angular, mat-expansion-panel

I am using Angular `<mat-expansion-panel>` in my project.

I am unable to display `Frate, Kunda and date` and `its value` on `one line`.

I have tried using various css properties such as `white-space: nowrap;` but none of them are working for me

Working Demo - https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-expansion-panel-en61pv?file=app%2Fexpansion-overview-example.html

.html

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-7">
    <dl class="row property_set">
      <mat-accordion style="width:50%">
        <mat-expansion-panel (opened)="panelOpenState = true" (closed)="panelOpenState = false">
          <mat-expansion-panel-header>
            <mat-panel-title>
              <dt class="col-sm-4 record_property">Term</dt>
            </mat-panel-title>
            <mat-panel-description>
              <dd class="col-sm-8 record_property_value term_name">

                <span >
              {{name1}}
            </span>
              </dd>
            </mat-panel-description>
          </mat-expansion-panel-header>

          <dt class="col-sm-4 record_property">Frate</dt>
          <dd class="col-sm-8 record_property_value" data-property-type="select">{{id}}</dd>

          <dt class="col-sm-4 record_property">Kunda</dt>
          <dd class="col-sm-8 record_property_value" data-property-type="select">

            <span>{{text1}}</span>
          </dd>

          <dt class="col-sm-4 record_property">Date</dt>
          <dd class="col-sm-8 record_property_value">{{date}}</dd>
        </mat-expansion-panel>
      </mat-accordion>
    </dl>
  </div>
</div>
```

.ts file

```
export class AppComponent {
   term: string = 'This is term'
  name1: string = 'This is name'
  id: string = 'This is id'
  text: string = 'This is text'
  text1: string = 'This is term1'
  date: string = 'This is date'
  panelOpenState = false;
}
```

Comment: try adding `display:inline-flex` in `dd` and `dt` as default style for `dd` and `dt` is `display:block;`

Comment: I tried adding `display: inline-flex` to both ```dd and dt```. That did not work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
::ng-deep .property_set .mat-expansion-panel-body {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
}
```

Add it in your `css` file. It should work.
[image]

Comment: Thanks for reply, this seems to be working fine on your side but not in my project. Can you please check this - https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-expansion-panel-en61pv?file=app%2Fexpansion-overview-example.html

Comment: I can see your content has updated now. Updated your [Stackblitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-expansion-panel-zmnsfy?file=app/expansion-overview-example.css) check once please

Comment: Thank you, adding these css helped the issue , but it is `not aligned with This is name`. Can you help me what changes should I make to make them align?

Comment: I fixed the issue based upon the question you asked in here. To solve the issue you're talking about need some time. We might have to change the HTML structure but I don't think you would want that. Meantime you could try using padding and removing the margin in your second column.